# Python Dynamic value in text

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

```
count = 1
maxcount = 6

while(count <= maxcount): 
    print locals()["test_"+str(count)]+str(".png")

    count += 1
```

I was hoping for the output

```
test_1.png
test_2.png
test_3.png
test_4.png
test_5.png
test_6.png
```

Instead I get an error

```
KeyError: 'test_1'
```

Also, is it possible to add a `0` after the `_` if the value is less than 10?

I am using this loop for saving files, but figured that this MWE would be less labour and would easily apply to my issue

Comment: Why are you using `locals()`? And there's no need to convert a string to a string: `str(".png")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that error because you have not created a variable named 'test_1' in your local scope. Instead of using a while loop, it is easier to use a for loop. Also, there's a thing called string formatting, which is easier to use than string concatenation.

```
maxcount = 6
for i in range(1, maxcount+1):
    filename = 'test_{}.png'.format(i)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Why even use the `maxcount` variable? `for i in range(1,7)` would work just the same and there's no use for the extra variable.

Comment: just wanted to point it out so the OP knows. I used to end up with tons of extra variables in my code that I didn't need because of refactoring. Also to let any future SO users know they don't need it.